# Importing into Wordpress via RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, import, migrate

I am creating a wordpress blog for a magazine. They have a legacy blog engine with years of archives, and I am trying to migrate all of the content into wordpress posts. My method is to import all of the content via the RSS feed.

I am using a plugin called [Feed Wordpress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) which imports RSS feeds into posts. The only problem is that is only imports the ten latest posts. Is there anyway you can modify the RSS feed's URL to display all of the posts? Or there is another method out there that can backup/export an entire blog via RSS or XML?  I need all of this archived content on the wordpress platform, and the only way I can access it is via the RSS feed. I don't have any other information about the blog engine that is powering the site currently, but I know it doesn't have any export functionality. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is the old blog engine? Depending on what the old blog is, you still might be able to export from the database. Wordpress imports many formats, and even if the old blog format isn't directly supported, there are ways to process the blog posts to import them into WordPress.

Failing that, you need to look in the old blog code to find how to set the RSS feed to show more (or all) entries.

**Edit:** For Google Reader, it looks like you can go to http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://mydomain.com/feed/ in Firefox and then view source to get an XML file.

Or try a standalone RSS client reader for Win* or OS X and see if it gives you the full history of feed items, and then export from that.

Comment: Im not sure what the old blog engine is....Im hoping I can somehow export it. Before I get my hands dirty with it, I was just trying to see if there is a way to view all the blog posts RSS feeds at once. In google reader, it lets you view them all, but there are no export functions.

Comment: that does work; however, it still displays just the latest 10 posts

Comment: Then you have to go into your old blog system and find out how to set the RSS feed to show all items, if that's possible. Or export from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Wordpress import tools might work for you.  There is a RSS import tool that would import more than 10 posts.  You should try it out on a test site first because there is no way to tell how well it will pull all the content from the other blog.  If it has a lot of posts that don't import correctly you'd have a ton of work deleting posts :)